# Understanding typescript syntax in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am new to Angular 4 and Typescript. I followed the "Angular-tour-of-heroes" tutorial available in Angular.io website. Since Angular 4 uses typescript for defining components etc., I wanted to understand more about typescript, so I looked for documentation in internet. I got further confused when I read the documentation for typescript available at 'http://devdocs.io/typescript/'. When I compared the syntaxes given in the documentation and Angular code, I found a lot of differences.

1) Functions are declared with 'function' keyword, but in Angular, function is not declared with 'function' keyword.

2) Types are declared using 'let' keyword in documentation, but in Angular there is no 'let' keyword.

There are many differences like this. So, I am confused about where to look for the documentation for TypeScript ( and why Angular uses a different syntax.

Comment: I am not sure why this is being downvoted. Is this not a programming question? What is wrong in this question?.

Comment: Don't learn typescript, or angular, or anything javascript-related until you understand javascript, plain and simple, although I didn't downvote your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**"1) Functions are declared with 'function' keyword, but in Angular, function is not declared with 'function' keyword."**

Angular is based on **classes** (ES6 feature), every Angular component is a class. Inside classes you don't need `function` keyword to declare a method, you can just write `yourMethod() {//do stuff}` and it will be a valid syntax.

**"2) Types are declared using 'let' keyword in documentation, but in Angular there is no 'let' keyword."**

`let` and `const` are ES6 features too, they are analogues to regular `var` but with some differences. In Angular you normally use these keywords inside methods or outside classes, so they are here, you just didn't saw them yet.

**"Why Angular uses a different syntax"**

There is no difference: Angular is written on Typescript, and don't forget that Angular - is a **framework**, and developing with Angular is not the same as developing with regular Javascript or Typescript, but if you understand ES6 and Typescript - it will not be a a big deal to get an understanding of what's generally is going on in Angular components.

**So my recommendations are:**

**1. Learn ES6**

**2. Learn Typescript**

And then start learning Angular.

Comment: Okay. I understood it now!.

Comment: @KurioZ7 nice to hear that the answer helps

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [official TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html)?

Also, as for me, [ng-book2](https://www.ng-book.com/2/) is great for beginners to start from. You can read in it about TypeScript too.

And, it is very important, it is not necessary that Angular 4 is working with the latest TypeScript version. So, some of the features can be not implemented in Angular 4 yet. Usually, there is an information about it in the changelog.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Angular use normal Typescript. There's none Angular specific Typescript. And Typescript is Javascript + Type.

Next, answer your questions below:

1) Functions are declared with 'function' keyword, but in Angular, function is not declared with 'function' keyword.

Please read and understand Javascript class: http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html. Function in a class do not need to declare with `function` keywords. This is standard javascript.

2) Types are declared using 'let' keyword in documentation, but in Angular there is no 'let' keyword.

Property in Javascript class do not need to declare with `let` or `const`. Please read and understand Javascript class: http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html. Eg.

```
class Something { constructor() { this.greet = 'hey' } }
```

In addition, with Typescript, property is defined like this. Read more about Typescript class. https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/08/22/advanced-typescript-concepts-classes-types/

```
class Something { greet:string; constructor() { this.greet = 'hey' } }
```

Once again, Angular did not choose any different syntax. It's normal Typescript and Javascript.

There are some good articles by Todd Motto on Typescript. Check it out here: https://toddmotto.com/resources/typescript

Comment: You have mentioned "It's normal Typescript and Javascript".  If it is so, can you help me understand, how do I differentiate between typescript and javascript in a .ts file?.